# how to pass multiple parameter in render action in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my source code is

```
.modal-body
  =render 'folders/pieces/update', id: @piece , folder_id: @piece.folder_id
```

It throws an error:

```
undefined method 'folder_id' for nil:NilClass
```

I want to pass two parameters in render page

Comment: Without trying to be snide, did you actually *read* the error message? It says exactly where the problem lies and gives no hint at all that it is related to passing render arguments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is valid and correct - it is exactly how you pass multiple params to render.

The error comes from the fact, that `@piece` is `nil`.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is absolutely correct for multiple parameters. The error is because you are getting `nil` value in `@piece`.
You can simply handle `nil` values as follows:
`@piece.try(:folder_id)`

And your code will look something like:

```
.modal-body =render 'folders/pieces/update', id: @piece , folder_id: @piece.try(:folder_id)
```

This will not throw any error in case of `nil` value.

Comment: While this answer is factually correct, I would advise against it. `#try` had its place when `nil` is an expected and common value for the variable, but for an action like this (which looks like a form being saved)  I would assume that `nil` would suggest an error. So `try` would just hide the error from the developer/log file - the user will notice though.